# Why error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='" in php cli code in variable assignment?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I'm trying to test max execution time by creating an infinite loop on the cli.

```
root@server [~]# php -d max_execution_time=2 -r "$i=1;while($i>0) { $i++ }"
```

I get this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in Command line code on line 1
```

So I just try this:

```
root@server [~]# php -r "$i=0;"
```

And I get the same error. Are variables not allowed in the cli? lol

PHP 5.5.20 on Centos 6.

Comment: Shell interpolation. So the PHP syntax error is just a by-product of `$i` getting stripped in double quotes by bash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using PHP CLI you should put the code into single quotes.

```
php -d max_execution_time=2 -r '$i=1;while($i>0) { $i++; }'
```

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php